# How do I upgrade ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: upgrade

I'm a newbie to Linux using Ubuntu 16.04 and my manager ask me to upgrade my system to 17. So I need your help to guide me how to upgrade my system to 17.

Comment: It is not a good idea to upgrade an LTS release to a non-LTS. And there is no Ubuntu 17, or Ubuntu 17.0.

Comment: @Pilot6, doesn't it depend on how you ended on 16.04 ? If you start at, as an example, 15.04, you will upgrade to 15.10, then 16.04. And then you probably will go to 16.10 and 17.04. Unless you have a policy about only running LTS's .. but we can't read that out of the question.

Comment: @SorenA once you hit a LTS (eg. 16.04) it should remain on 16.04LTS unless the user forces the 'upgrade' to 16.10 or a non-LTS until 18.04LTS upgrade is available (and then its 18.04.1 usually as per https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html)

Comment: Is your "manager" in the question your boss at work, or the update-manager program on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 it's a so called [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) "Long Term Support" somehow the Ubuntu stable flavor

[17.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes?_ga=2.151948537.1788193687.1508149608-220577131.1479756796) isn't LTS, the support ends in January 2018

Its your choice to use an LTS or non-LTS version but as @Pilot6 isn't a good idea to upgrade from a LTS to a non-LTS version.

If u want your system to stop asking u to do that go to "System Settings
--> Software & Updates --> Updates" and at "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" select the For Long-term Support versions option

Comment: I assume you meant "it isn't a good idea to upgrade from **an LTS** version to **a non-LTS** version"

Comment: wops! ur right. edited